# C Programming: Convert Hex Int to Char*

Tags: c, char, int

My question is how I would go about converting something like:

```
    int i = 0x11111111;
```

to a character pointer? I tried using the itoa() function but it gave me a floating-point exception.

Comment: You mean char *cp = (char * ) i; ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "hex int".  This is just a normal `int`, whose value you happen to have specified in hex representation.

Comment: That's not a "hex int".  It's just an "int".  "Hex int" is one representation of an integer.  Or a view of the value in base 16.  To turn an int into a pointer of any type, you just cast it:  char * p = ( char * )i;   Probably not a great practice, however.

Comment: Do you want `(char*)0x11111111`, or `"0x11111111"`?

Comment: @Ation yes this is what i want

Comment: If I cast it it gives a segementation error.

Comment: @Bhubhu: I bet it doesn't give a segmentation error when you cast it. I bet the segmentation error comes later, when you do something with that pointer. If you don't show your code, then people will make wrong guesses about it, and waste everybody's time.

Comment: "but it gave me a floating-point exception" - really floating-point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`itoa` is non-standard. Stay away.

One possibility is to use `sprintf` and the proper format specifier for hexa i.e. `x` and do:

```
char str[ BIG_ENOUGH + 1 ];
sprintf(str,"%x",value);
```

However, the problem with this computing the size of the `value` array. You have to do with some guesses and [FAQ 12.21](http://c-faq.com/stdio/sprintfsize.html) is a good starting point.

The number of characters required to represent a number in any base `b` can be approximated by the following formula:

> ⌈log<sub>b</sub>(n + 1)⌉

Add a couple more to hold the `0x`, if need be, and then your `BIG_ENOUGH` is ready.

Comment: For int (4 bytes) sufficient size is easily determinated: 9 for hex, 11 for decimal, 33 for binary.

Comment: @Ruben: Without the `0x` prefix for hex, yes.

Comment: Of cource, without prefix - only for number itself and \0 at the end of string.

Answer (score 1):

```
char buffer[20];
```

Then:

```
sprintf(buffer, "%x", i);
```

Or:

```
itoa(i, buffer, 16);
```

Character pointer to buffer can be `buffer` itself (but it is const) or other variable:

```
char *p = buffer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the sprintf() function like this -- `sprintf(charBuffer, "%x", i);`
 -- I think will work very well.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: Why did you add a cast?  It provides no benefit at all, and is potentially harmful (disabling useful compiler warnings that would catch type errors during compile instead of crashing at runtime).

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for catching this. I don't program enough in C anymore and just plain forgot that rule.

Comment: The edit you approved @BenVoigt was rejected. I just submitted again.

Comment: I rolled back this answer.  @octopusgrabbus - if you want to answer a question, please do so as an answer.  Please don't edit another answer to add your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `sprintf()` function to convert an integer to hexadecimal should accomplish your task.

Here is an example:

```
int i = 0x11111111;

char szHexPrintBuf[10];

int ret_code = 0;

ret_code = sprintf(szHexPrintBuf, "%x", i);

if(0 > ret_code)
{ 
   something-bad-happend();
}
```