# Convert unicoded string to corresponding string in C

Tags: c, string, unicode, char

I need to convert a unicoded string to its appropriate language. I need to read from a text file line by line. There is a possibility that a line may contain a unicode some thing like this

> \xE6\xAC\xA2\xE8\xBF\x8E

This is basically a chinese text which is equal to

> 欢迎

Now I need to remove this line (\xE6\xAC\xA2\xE8\xBF\x8E) from text file, convert this unicode to chinese text, append this chinese text to the text file.

Below is the content of my data.txt file:

```
testing
programming
\xE6\xAC\xA2\xE8\xBF\x8E
development
```

I would like to get the file content as:

```
testing
programming
development
欢迎
```

Below is what I have done so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAX 256

  int main() 
  {
        int ctr = 0;
        char ch;
        FILE *fptr1, *fptr2;
        char fname[MAX] = "data.txt";
        char str[MAX], temp[] = "temp.txt";
        char str2[256];

        fptr1 = fopen(fname, "r");
        if (!fptr1) 
        {
                printf(" File not found or unable to open the input file!!\n");
                return 0;
        }
        fptr2 = fopen(temp, "w"); // open the temporary file in write mode 
        if (!fptr2) 
        {
                printf("Unable to open a temporary file to write!!\n");
                fclose(fptr1);
                return 0;
        }

        // copy all contents to the temporary file except the specific line with unicode characters
        while (!feof(fptr1)) 
        {
            strcpy(str, "\0");
            fgets(str, MAX, fptr1);
            if (!feof(fptr1)) 
            {
                ctr++;
                if(strstr(str,"\\")!=NULL)
                {
                    memset(str2,'\0',sizeof(str2));
                    printf("Input String Contains Unicode Character\n");                    
                    str[strlen(str)-1]='\0';

                    sprintf(str2,"echo %s >> data.txt",str);
                    printf("Final String: %s\nUnicode String Size: %ld\n",str2,strlen(str));
                    system(str2);
                }
                else
                {

                    fprintf(fptr2, "%s", str);                  
                }
            }
        }
        fclose(fptr1);
        fclose(fptr2);
        remove(fname);          // remove the original file 
        rename(temp, fname);    // rename the temporary file to original name
/*------ Read the file ----------------*/
   fptr1=fopen(fname,"r"); 
            ch=fgetc(fptr1); 
          printf(" Now the content of the file %s is : \n",fname); 
          while(ch!=EOF) 
            { 
                printf("%c",ch); 
                 ch=fgetc(fptr1); 
            }
        fclose(fptr1);
/*------- End of reading ---------------*/
        return 0;

  }
```

When tried to compile and run this code, below is the output I am seeing

```
Input String Contains Unicode Character
Final String: echo \xE6\xAC\xA2\xE8\xBF\x8E >> data.txt
Unicode String Size: 24
 Now the content of the file data.txt is : 
testing
programming
development
xE6xACxA2xE8xBFx8E
```

The same code when changed the below lines, it was working as expected

```
 sprintf(str2,"echo %s >> data.txt",str); 
 sprintf(str2,"echo %s >> data.txt","\xE6\xAC\xA2\xE8\xBF\x8E");
```

But when the value is read from file it was not working.

Also this line, the string is identified as unicode string with correct size

```
printf("Final String: %s\nUnicode String Size: %ld\n",str2,strlen(str));
The String Size: 6
```

Can some one please let me know, how to convert the value to chinese when read from text file.

Comment: You seem to be confused. UTF-8 *is* Unicode. Which other Unicode representation do you hope to convert it to? Maybe see also https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ and http://utf8everywhere.com

Comment: ... But most probably the answer is *You don't need to write any code at all.* You just need to understand what it is you're looking at.

Comment: @tripleee I would like to convert the displayed string from "\xE6\xAC\xA2\xE8\xBF\x8E" to "欢迎"

Comment: So `perl -pe 's/\\x(\X{2})/chr(hex("0x$1"))/ge' <<<'\xE6\xAC\xA2\xE8\xBF\x8E'` basically? Is there a particular reason you want to reinvent this in C?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C Programming: Convert Hex Int to Char\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770257/c-programming-convert-hex-int-to-char)

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the pointer in perl. My application is in C. So I need to find out a way to get this done in C only

Comment: The proposed duplicate shows how to parse \xXX in C. There is nothing really about Unicode here.

Comment: Aside: Why code `fgets(str, MAX, fptr1);
            if (!feof(fptr1))` instead of `if(fgets(str, MAX, fptr1))`?  The 2nd is more idiomatic and catches rare read error too.

Comment: @tripleee It seems to me that the proposed duplicate does just the opposite, conversion from integer to ascii, no?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to identify the `\x` positions in your line, say pointer `p` then points to the next character. Now

```
char hex[3] = { p[0], p[1], 0 }; 
char val = strtoul(hex, 0, 16);
p += 2;
```

will return the value of the following two bytes interpreted in hex in `val`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the conversion done. Below is my final code

```
                if(strstr(str,"\\")!=NULL)
                {
                    memset(str2,'\0',sizeof(str2));
                    printf("Input String Contains Unicode Character\n");                    
                    str[strlen(str)-1]='\0';


                    sprintf(str2,"echo %s | sed \'s/[\\\\x]//g\' | xxd -r -p >> data.txt",str);
                    printf("Final String: %s\nUnicode String Size: %ld\n",str2,strlen(str));
                    system(str2);
                }
```

Thanks for all your response and thanks @chux for your pointer

Comment: this is overkill. if you want to unescape a literal string containing hex values then just remove the escape string `\x` then convert those hex to bytes and print directly. Don't you know how to convert from hex to binary?