# How to convert hexadecimal array to decimal using C language

Tags: c

Hello I want to know how to convert a hexadecimal array to a decimal
here's my `block`

`uint8_t block[8] = {0xb,0xb,0xb,0xa,0xa,0xa,0xa,0xa};`
here's my code

```
#include "stdint.h"

void main() {

   uint8_t block[8] = {0xb,0xb,0xb,0xa,0xa,0xa,0xa,0xa};

   uint8_t key[16]  = {0xa,0xa,0xa,0xb,0xb,0xb,0xb,0xb,
                       0xa,0xa,0xa,0xa,0xa,0xa,0xa,0xa};

   UART1_Init(9600);  // Initialisation de l’UART1 à 9600 bps
   UART1_Write_Text("message:");
   UART1_Write_Text(block);
   UART1_Write_Text(" TEA Encryption:");
   TEA_Enc(block, key);
   UART1_Write_Text(block);

   UART1_Write_Text("TEA Decryption:");
   TEA_Dec(block, key);
   UART1_Write_Text(block);
}
```

For example if i display `block` i want to have as result like 123456
thank you in advance

Comment: There is nothing to convert. A number exists in all possible bases simultaneously.

Comment: hello Eugene Sh do you see ```block``` i want to be in decimal if that is possible

Comment: As I said. It is a bunch of numbers and the numbers are agnostic of the way you are representing them. That is `uint8_t block[8] = {0xb,0xb...` is exactly the same as `uint8_t block[8] = {11,11...`

Comment: You need to clarify your terminology and question. “Hexadecimal” is a notation in which 16 symbols are used to express a number in a base-16 positional numeral system. Commonly the characters “0” to “9” and “A” to “F” (or their lowercase counterparts) are used as the 16 symbols. One could also use the numbers 0 to 15. Your `block` is an array that contains the numbers 11 and 10. “Decimal” is a notation in which ten symbols are used in a base-10 system. Converting hexadecimal to decimal would result in a numeral made of the digits “0” to “9”. It would not be “hello world”. Those are characters.

Comment: The characters form a string. The string is not hexadecimal or decimal. One might have hexadecimal numerals that represent numbers, and those numbers might be code for characters, likely ASCII codes for characters. So one could take a list of hexadecimal numerals, convert each to a number, and then print the characters represented in ASCII by those numbers. If that is what you mean, you ought to rewrite your question to clarify it, and you ought to show a real example with the actual numerals to start with and the actual string to write.

Comment: Additionally, you should show where these numerals are coming from. If you know the numerals already and can write them in source code, then you can write `unsigned char block[] = { 0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, … };` and `puts(block);`, and that will do the job. If you want to read the numerals from input and convert them, you will need more code.

Comment: It almost seems like you are wanting to print the array as characters, and not as the number equivalent. I would check out this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770257/c-programming-convert-hex-int-to-char) and the documentation for [sprintf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf). If you wish to display the number equivalent, then I would use print and %d

Comment: thank you @EricPostpischil like a said the ```block``` is in hexadecimal if I can convert it and display it in decimal it will be good

Comment: Commenters have been trying to say that `block` is *not* in hexadecimal, only the way you initialised it. It contains numerica data, and decimal, binary, hexadecimal only make sense in the context of how you print the values for human consumption.

Comment: Your requirements leave a lot to the reader's own imagination. Each array element is 8 bits, so does it contain one or two hexadecimal digits? And is the array big endian or little endian? An example with actual numbers would help. According to you, what _is_ the decimal representation of `{0xb,0xb,0xb,0xa,0xa,0xa,0xa,0xa}`? I am pretty sure it's _not_ 123456.

Comment: the number ```0xb``` is equal to 11 in decimal but the problem is that block is an ```array``` you see so I do not really know how to convert it in decimal kind if you can transform ```{0xb, 0xa, ... ......... etc.}``` to ```123456``` do you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Eric and Eugene has said in the comments, ***there is no way to convert a hexidecimal number to a decimal number***.  Hexidecimal or decimal only exist in the code you write.  Once a compiler sees a number it will store it in memory in it's own representation.

Here's an example of how you can write numbers in different representations in your code.  All the numbers I write in the following code are the same.  The program does not change, no matter which one you use.

```
int x = 0x10;
// stored in memory as:
// |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|

int x = 16;
// stored in memory as:
// |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|

int x = 0b00000000000000000000000000010000;
// stored in memory as:
// |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|

int x = 020;
// stored in memory as:
// |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|
```

So for your example you `block` can be represented in either of these ways

```
uint8_t block_hex[8] = {0xb,0xb,0xb,0xa,0xa,0xa,0xa,0xa};
uint8_t block_dec[8] = {11,11,11,10,10,10,10,10};
```

Changing between hexidecimal and decimal will not change the behavior of your program.